# How do you get a Radio Button to change text color in html with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

Here is the code I Have cant figure out how to get the value of the radio button to be read by jquery and then into a function that will then change the color of the text.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/3898/

HTML:

```
<span id="quotechange"> HEllloooooo </span>

<div id="mydiv">
                Color: 
                    <label class="color1"><input type="radio"  name="color" value="color1" checked="checked">Black</label>
                    <label class="color2"><input type="radio"  name="color" value="color2" >Purple</label>
                    <label class="color3"><input type="radio"  name="color" value="color3" >Orange</label>
                    <label class="color4"><input type="radio"  name="color" value="color4" >Red</label> <br>

                Style:
                    <label class="stylebold"><input type="checkbox" name="style1" value="stylebold" > Bold</label>
                    <label class="styleitalic"><input type="checkbox" name="style2" value="styleitalic" > Italic</label>
           </div>
```

CSS:

```
.color1 {
    color: black;
}
.color2 {
    color: purple;
}
.color3 {
    color: orange;
}
.color4 {
    color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#mydiv input').click(colorClick($('input[name=color]:checked', '#mydiv').val()));


function colorClick(color) {
    if(color == "color1") {
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color2");
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color3");
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color4");
        $("#quotechange").addClass("color1");
    }
    else if(color == "color2"){
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color1");
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color3");
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color4");
        $("#quotechange").addClass("color2");
    }
    else if(color == "color3"){
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color1");
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color2");
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color4");
        $("#quotechange").addClass("color3");
    }
    else if(color == "color4"){
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color1");
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color3");
        $("#quotechange").removeClass("color2");
        $("#quotechange").addClass("color4");
    }
}
```

Comment: your code here is `$('input[name=color]:checked', '#mydiv')`, but your jsFiddle is `$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm')`? is this intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple use `$(this).val()`

```
$('#mydiv input:radio').on('change', function() {
    $('#test').attr('class', '').addClass($(this).val()); 
});


$('#mydiv input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $('#test').addClass($(this).val()); 
    //or if you use this, it will take care when unchecked
    //$('#test').toggleClass($(this).val()); 
});
```

Demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/RhnvU/3908/

**Update**

Issue fixed: `When bold and/or italic are checked and a new color is picked the bold and italic remain checked but the value gets reset for them`

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/RhnvU/3910/

```
$('#mydiv input:radio').on('change', function () {    
    var checkedboxes = $('#mydiv input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get(); 

    $('#test').attr('class', checkedboxes.join(' ')).addClass($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Would it be likewise for the checkboxes ?

Comment: @Bailey507 definitely,with this change `input:checkbox`, and I would NOT clear the existing class by using `attr('class', '')` for the checkbox

Comment: @Bailey507 see the full working example: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/RhnvU/3908/

Comment: One last thing with the checkboxes I was wondering if there was a way of doing both boxes at the same time. without checking one and having the other cancel out?

Comment: @Bailey507 you mean it can be either italic or bold, but not both at the same time?

Comment: Would like to be able to bold and italic at the same time.

Comment: you mean with one click you want both bold and italic applied? then why would you want to have two separate checkboxs?

Comment: Totally disregard, I had a line wrong and it would only do one or the other with i checked both boxes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: When bold and/or italic are checked and a new color is picked the bold and italic remain checked but the value gets reset for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mydiv input').click(function(){
    colorClick($('input[name=color]:checked', '#mydiv').val()) 
});
```

> The syntax of your click function was wrong except that what you did was right and you could use `$(this)` instead of `$('input[name=color]:checked', '#mydiv')`

[DEMO Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/3906/)